# Normal distribution, propability of cost.

Tags: statistics

Problem: b) http://cl.ly/image/3a3l3142432M

Attempt:
I find the cost to be 458 000 $. See [calculations](http://cl.ly/image/0t0C2u011o1u) in the link and/or my thoughts here:

Let cost be $c$.

$F_Z(\frac{c-500000}{50000})=0.2$ and then I find $z=0.84$ gives $P=0.8$

Thus $z=-0.84=\frac{c-500000}{50000}$

Am I right? I've got no solutions-manuel.

Answer (score 0):

\$457,918.90, or \$458,000 to three decimal places. Well done.